# Extracting text between two markers and handling Backslashes in Regex for Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a few URLs in a file, some of them are embedded between specific start and end tags whereas others are not. I only need to extract the ones which are embedded in between the start and end tags.

A line in my `inputfile.txt` looks like the following:

```
some gibberish data-start=\"https:\/\/cdn.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/1.jpg\" data-end this is useless text, some gibberishhh data-start=\"https:\/\/cdn.net\/hphotos-xaf1\/2.jpg\" data-end some gibberish fake-data-start=\"https:\/\/cdn.net\/hphotos-xaf1\/2.jpg\" fake-data-end
```

The start and end tags of the URLs that I need are `data-start` and `data-end` as opposed to `fake-data-start` and `fake-data-end`.

Now I'm using the following regex in Python to extract the aforementioned URLs:

```
(?<=\ data-start=\\\")([^"]+\.[^"]+\.[^"]+)(?=\"\ data-end)
```

I believe the above Regex works which I tested from [this link](http://regex101.com/r/fD1jH4)

and My Python Code is:

```
import re
import string
import sys

s = re.compile('(?<=\ data-start=\\\")([^"]+\.[^"]+\.[^"]+)(?=\"\ data-end)')

fin = open('inputfile.txt') 

for line in fin: 
    m = s.findall(line)

if m:       
    print m
```

However, my Python code is unable to find the URLs, on the other hand if I remove all backslashes from my file then the above code works fine. I haven't been able to explain this difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash serves as an escape character. Therefore; for every *single* (`\`) backslash you need *two* backslashes (`\\`). You can use the following regular expression here:

```
(?<=data-start=\\").*?(?=\\" data-end)
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<=              # look behind to see if there is:
   data-start=    #   'data-start='
  \\              #   '\'
  "               #   '"'
)                 # end of look-behind
.*?               # any character except \n (0 or more times)
(?=               # look ahead to see if there is:
  \\              #   '\'
  " data-end      #   '" data-end'
)                 # end of look-ahead
```

**Note:** If your data spans multi-line, use the inline `(?s)` modifier forcing the dot to match newline characters.

```
(?s)(?<=data-start=\\").*?(?=\\" data-end)
```

**Final solution**:

```
import re

myfile = open('inputfile.txt', 'r')
regex  = re.compile(r'(?<=data-start=\\").*?(?=\\" data-end)')

for line in myfile:
    matches = regex.findall(line)
    for m in matches:
        print m
```

Output

```
https:\/\/cdn.net\/hphotos-ak-xfa1\/1.jpg
https:\/\/cdn.net\/hphotos-xaf1\/2.jpg
```

Comment: This works as well, and is perhaps more compact I guess.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to put down the explanation, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have too many backslashes. It looks to me like you could simplify your regex to something like:

```
(?<= data-start=\\")([^".]+\.[^".]+\.[^"\\]+)
```

Please note that the original `[^"]+\.`, which means any character that is not a double quote, then a dot, will first eat all the dots, then backtrack, which is why I added the dots in the character classes.

In Python, something like:

```
s = re.compile(r'(?<= data-start=\\")([^".]+\.[^".]+\.[^"\\]+)')
```

Comment: Indeed that works, although if i retain `(?<= data-start=\\\")` then that works as well.

Comment: Why would you think, the bigger regex works on the link that I posted? Is there a difference in treatment of the Regex?

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar Probably because you had 3 backslashes where you needed two. :)